# hashtables and arrays powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to store in Item of hashtable 2 int variables. But cannot undestand how to store it:

```
    $hash = @{}
    if($hash.contains($name) -eq $False){
        $value = 1
        $arr = @($my_var;$value)
        $hash.add($name,$arr)
    }else{
        $value = $hash.item($name)
        $value[1]++ #PROBLEM HERE
        $hash.item($name)[0] = $my_var
        $hash.item($name)[1] = $value
    }
```

Problem is that `$value[1]` not exists(Note1),  `$value[0]` contains also `$my_var` and `$value` with space.

Note1 - The '++' operator works only on numbers. The operand is a 'System.Object[]'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to update the `int`-value? If so, your problem is that you overwrite the `int`-value that was stored in `$hash.item($name)[1]` with not just an int, but the whole array. You're essentially creating this:

```
$hash.item($name) = @($my_var, $value, @($my_var, $value+1))
```

You could fix this by updating this line:

```
$hash.item($name)[1] = $value
```

to

```
$hash.item($name)[1] = $value[1]
```

If `$my_var` is always the same value, you could clean it up by replacing the whole item:

```
$my_var = "test"
$name = "nametest"
#$hash = @{}   #ran this first time to create ht before commenting it out to avoid overwriting the ht

if($hash.Contains($name) -eq $False){
    $value = 1
    $arr = @($my_var;$value)
    $hash.add($name,$arr)
}else{
    $value = $hash.item($name)
    $value[1]++
    $hash.item($name) = $value
}
```